# Numpy equivalent of Tensorflow's embedding_lookup function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

What would be a NumPy equivalent code to Tensorflow's `embedding_lookup` function?

In particular, what would be the NumPy equivalent of the last line of the following code block?

```
words = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, name='words')
...
embedding = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_params, words[:, i])
```

I'm not really sure about what `embedding_lookup` actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: tf.gather]

[tf.nn.embedding_lookup](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) works basically like [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather)(in above picture). It just get i-th slice of params("i" is element of indices), and concatenate slices in order of indices.

Comment: I think [np.take](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) is most similar with tf.nn.embedding_lookup.